# Object Oriented Java: External method calling with variable reference

Tags: java, class, variables, methods, external

Using BlueJ as the compiler for learning about external method calling/referencing. My goal is to learn more about calling methods from another class and how to reference variables from that class.

What I understand is that an external method call is essentially this:

`object.methodName(parameters);`

The current project that I'm working on asks me to go through an `ArrayList` and extract the balance of all accounts on the list. I am working with only two classes. `Bank.class` and `BankAccount.class` 
In `BankAccount.class` I have 4 methods; `withdraw()`, `deposit()`, `showBal()`, and `acctInfo()`. For Bank I have only two methods, `listAllAccounts()`, and `sumAllAccounts()`.

I am stuck on writing the code for `sumAllAccounts()` as it asks me to sum the balance of all `BankAccount.class` objects that are added to the `private ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts`

I don't need a straight forward answer, I am only here because i've exhausted my resources. In my course we have not discussed `static classes` or `null` yet so a lot of similar posts are difficult for me to understand.

I have read elsewhere that it is impossible to bring an instance variable from one class to another. So I'm curious how I am suppose to extract a `float` type variable into another class for calculation.

What I have written so far is:

```
private void sumAllAccounts()
{
   int index = 0;
   float bal = 0;
   float sum = 0;
   while(index < accounts.size()) {
      accounts.get(index);
      bal = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      sum = sum+bal;
      index++;
   }
   System.out.println("The total balance of all accounts listed are: " + sum);
}
```

I know balance should look at the indexed object at that moment and extract a balance that we can add to the sum. I don't know how to extract that balance. Once again this is just an example that I am working on so that I can better explain myself. The context of your response can be less specific.

Comment: `account.get(i).showBal()` ?

Comment: Can you try `bal = account.get(index).showBal()` ? I have no idea if return type of `showBal() ` is `Float` or not!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `showBal()` in class `BankAccount` returns a `float`:

```
public void sumAllAccounts() {
    float sum1 = 0;
    for(BankAccount bankAccount : accounts) {
        sum1 += bankAccount.showBal();
    }
    System.out.println("The total balance of all accounts listed are: " + sum1);

    // or
    int index = 0;
    float bal = 0;
    float sum2 = 0;
    while(index < accounts.size()) {
        bal = accounts.get(index).showBal();
        sum2 = sum2 + bal; // can be simplified to: sum2 += accounts.get(index).showBalance();
        index++;
    }
    System.out.println("The total balance of all accounts listed are: " + sum2);

    // or
    float sum3 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
        sum3 += accounts.get(i).showBal();
    }
    System.out.println("The total balance of all accounts listed are: " + sum3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a method called `showBal()` in your Bankaccount class and assuming it returns a float:

```
// first get() the account that you are working on
BankAccount currentAccount = account.get(i);

// then invoke the method to retrieve the balance
bal = currentAccount.showBal();
```

You should also use a for-loop instead of a while-loop:

```
float bal = 0;
float sum = 0;

for (int index = 0; index < account.size(); index++){

   BankAccount currentAccount = account.get(i);
   bal = currentAccount.showBal();
   sum += bal; // "sum += bal;" is a shorter way of coding "sum = sum + bal;"

}

System.out.println("The total balance of all accounts listed are: " + sum);
```

That way, you don't have to declare the index integer and use the index++. It's all included in the for-loop!

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = 0;
while(index < accounts.size()) {
    sum += accounts.get(index).showBal();
    index++;
}
```

Although when the list size is fixed, I prefer to use a *for loop*:

```
for(int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
    sum += accounts.get(i).showBal();
}
```

or a *for-each*:

```
for(BankAccount bankAccount : accounts) {
    sum += bankAccount.showBal();
}
```

Once you understand loops, you also can try to do it with Lambdas which is more elegant:

```
float sum = accounts.stream().reduce(0.0, (subtotal, element) -> subtotal + element.showBal());
```